# jQuery / Select2 trigger even when certain value selected

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 for a dropdown, what I want to do is when a certain value from the dropdown has been selected for it to trigger an event (ex. alert)

I have already tried the following ways, but with no success:

```
$(".js-dropdown").val(2)(function() {
  console.log("val2 selected")
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $('select').select2()
    .val("2", function(e) {
      console.log("value changed");
    })
});
```

What did I do wrong?

---

My Select2:

```
$(".js-dropdown").select2({
  placeholder: "Text",
  allowClear: false,
  closeOnSelect: false
});
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONeNro)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a [change event](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events-public) handler and call function if selected value is `2`

```js
var $sel = $(".js-dropdown");
$sel.select2({
  placeholder: "Text",
  allowClear: false,
  closeOnSelect: false
});

$sel.change(function() {
  if (this.value == 2)
    alert('2')
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-dropdown" style="width: 220px;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Dropdown-1</option>
  <option value="2">Dropdown-2</option>
  <option value="3">Dropdown-3</option>
  <option value="4">Dropdown-4</option>
  <option value="5">Dropdown-5</option>
  <option value="6">Dropdown-6</option>
  <option value="7">Dropdown-7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @ekclone : glad to help you\